# Uncaught TypeError: not a function, but the function exists

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following in my js file:

```
var Field_File = function( _ )
{
    var _objects = null;

    var Init = function( instance, json )
    {
         // load _objects
    }

    var ImgLoad = function( elem, type )
    {
        //do things with _objects
    }
}
```

Now in my PHP, I've got:

```
<img id="file_uploader2_button" src="http://localhost/img/icons/up.png" onload="Field_File.ImgLoad(this, 'img');">
```

I've verified that the JS is loading into my page properly, and I'm calling other JS functions via the same PHP page with no problems:

```
body onload="Field_File.Init( '1', {$json});"
```

But I currently get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Field_File.ImgLoad is not a function

Am I missing something in this call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the declaration of your module (a literal object) to

```
var Field_File = {
    Init: function( instance, json ){
    },
    ImgLoad: function( elem, type ){
        //do things
    }
}
```

If you want a scope to protect some private variables, use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
var Field_File = (function(){
    var _objects = null;
    var Init = function( instance, json ){
         // load _objects
    }

    var ImgLoad = function( elem, type ){
        //do things with _objects
    }

    return {
        Init:Init,
        ImgLoad:ImgLoad
    }
})();
```

Many variations are possible, so what is important is to understand what happens here so that you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: While this works, is there a way to do it with the code I had posted? I ask cause Field_File has some other objects(`var _objects = null;
`) that gets set in one method, but used in others. If not, its no worries. I think your method will be totally fine. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Yes, you can use a function to protect some vars. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Change `ImageLoad` to a property of Field_File using `this`. When declaring it with `var` here, you are somewhat simulating a private property.

```
var Field_File = function( _ )
    this.Init = function( instance, json )
    {
    }

    this.ImgLoad = function( elem, type )
    {
        //do things
    }
}
```